# python urllib error

Tags: python, python-3.x, request, urllib

so I have this code:

```
def crawl(self, url):
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    print(data)
```

but then when I call the function, it returns

```
    data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
```

what did I do wrong? I already imported urllib..

using python 3.1.3

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In python3, urllib is a package with three modules request, response, and error for its respective purposes.

Whenever you had  `import urllib` or `import urllib2` in Python2.
Replace them with

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.response
import urllib.error
```

The classs and methods are same.

BTW, use `2to3` tool if you converting from python2 to python3.

Answer (score 2):

`urllib.request` is a separate module; import it explicitly.